# Overriding function inside a object literal

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have following object literal:

```
var timeObject = {
    type: "double",
    grid: true,
    values: [
        //
    ],
    from_min: 0,
    to: 8,
    onChange: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
};
```

This object will be passed in to different places:

```
$("#sundayTime").ionRangeSlider(timeObject);
$("#tuesdayTime").ionRangeSlider(timeObject);
$("#wednesdayTime").ionRangeSlider(timeObject);
$("#thursdayTime").ionRangeSlider(timeObject);
$("#fridayTime").ionRangeSlider(timeObject);
$("#saturdayTime").ionRangeSlider(timeObject);
```

Now I want to change the default behavior (logging data in the console) to my custom logic for each one of them.

I know we can use techniques like [this one](https://j201.github.io/posts/2013-06-22-JS-Object-Literal-Inheritance.html) to achieve object literal inheritance:

```
function extend(proto, literal) {
    var result = Object.create(proto);
    Object.keys(literal).forEach(function(key) {
        result[key] = literal[key];
    });
    return result;
}
```

And for using it we have:

```
$("#thursdayTime").ionRangeSlider(extend(timeObject, {
    onChange: function (data) {
        console.log('thursdayTime');
    }
}));

$("#fridayTime").ionRangeSlider(extend(timeObject, {
    onChange: function (data) {
        console.log('fridayTime');
    }
}));
```

But I wonder if there an easier way for this this or not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: another way (instead of overriding handlers on each instance) would be a general handler which reacts differently based on binded arguments or object differentiation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using ES2015 you can:

```
Object.assign({}, timeObject, {
  onChange: function(data) {
    console.log('whooof');
  } 
})
```

Comment: wouldn't it b simpler (and DRYer) to create a function that returns the time obejct?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of copying all the properties to a new object, you may use real inheritance.

```
Object.assign(Object.create(timeObject), {
  onChange: function(data) {
    console.log('whooof');
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about performance, tho u can write a function that returns this object literal:

```
function getConfig (onChange) {
  return timeObject = {
    type: "double",
    grid: true,
    values: [
        //
    ],
    from_min: 0,
    to: 8,
    onChange: onChange
  };
}

$("#fridayTime").ionRangeSlider(getConfig(function (data) {
  console.log('I am friday data:', data)
}));
```

if all the days are treated (more or less) equal, you could can simplify this logic:

```
function getConfig (day) {
  return timeObject = {
    type: "double",
    grid: true,
    values: [
        //
    ],
    from_min: 0,
    to: 8,
    onChange: function (data) {
      console.log('I am', day, 'data:', data)
    }
  };
}

$("#fridayTime").ionRangeSlider(getConfig('friday'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything much shorter (if shorter is easier) outside of using another library's method (as suggested) or adding an additional wrapper function like this:

```
function eto(obj, onChangeFn){
    return extend(obj, {
        onChange: onChangeFn
    });
}

$("#thursdayTime").ionRangeSlider(eto(timeObject, function(data){
    console.log('thursdayTime');
}));
```